# How can I debug a git alias?

Tags: git

Debugging `git` aliases with shell commands and quoting can be difficult.

How can I see what `git` is executing for a given alias?

Answer (score 12):

In your `.gitconfig`, add the following:

```
debug = !GIT_TRACE=1 git
```

Then you can run `git debug <aliasname>`, for example:

> ```
> $ git debug s
> 17:34:48.611406 git.c:563               trace: exec: 'git-s'
> 17:34:48.611696 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'git-s'
> 17:34:48.613262 git.c:286               trace: alias expansion: s => 'status' '--short'
> 17:34:48.613338 git.c:563               trace: exec: 'git-status' '--short'
> 17:34:48.613350 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'git-status' '--short'
> 17:34:48.615319 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'status' '--short'
>  M app/models/user.rb
>  M test/integration/users_edit_test.rb
> ?? html
> ```

Comment: IMO that's overengeneering ;-) One can merely do `export GIT_TRACE=1` before executing an alias to get the same effect. Or just stick `GIT_TRACE=1` before invocation of the alias on the command line, like in `$ GIT_TRACE=1 git myalias --arg1 --arg2 ...`

Comment: That's true - I guess my memory isn't as good as yours and I'm lazier :)  I actually call the alias `db` myself.

Comment: Using the config file also allows this to work under Windows/Powershell.