# git log alias fails , but running the full command explicitly succeeds

Tags: git, alias

I have seen a couple other related questions and tried to avoid the pitfalls:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51886432/959179
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68079866/959179
but these did not manage to fix the issue.

so in `~/.gitconfig` I have :

```
[alias]
    lf1= !git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%x09%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%ai%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) - %C(dim magenta)%an%C(reset) - %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)'
```

this is a one-liner git log printout.

when I use it on its own as `git lf1` it works correctly printing the git log as one-liners.

but when I try to track down info for a specific file it no longer works:

```
$ git lf1 7bddc5ead9 conf/distro/aos.conf
fatal: ambiguous argument 'conf/distro/aos.conf': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

if I add a separator "--" as suggested I will get a wrong printout - not the changes in the file up to and including version with the given commit ID.

I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39468026/959179 to help me debug the alias and the result is the same:

```
$ git debug lf1 7bddc5ead9 conf/distro/aos.conf
00:37:57.610634 git.c:703               trace: exec: git-lf1 7bddc5ead9 conf/distro/aos.conf
00:37:57.610680 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-lf1 7bddc5ead9 conf/distro/aos.conf
00:37:57.610964 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: 'git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'\''%x09%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%ai%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) - %C(dim magenta)%an%C(reset) - %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)'\''' 7bddc5ead9 conf/distro/aos.conf
00:37:57.612841 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate '--format=format:%x09%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%ai%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) - %C(dim magenta)%an%C(reset) - %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' 7bddc5ead9 conf/distro/aos.conf
fatal: ambiguous argument 'conf/distro/aos.conf': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

but then if I copy the last trace line (i.e. "*00:37:57.612841 git.c:439               trace: built-in:*" ,  the one just above "*fatal: ambiguous argument ...*") and paste and run it in CLI, I will get the expected printout.

what am I missing here and the alias fails when in CLI it works ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem: if I run `git lf1 <commitid> <path>`, it runs without errors (using git version 2.25.1).

Comment: @larsks I have the same git version but I get this error :(